# Why does my text's position get messed up when going into windowed mode?

Tags: html, css

Hey so I have this html code and it works perfectly fine when I'm viewing it in full screen. However, when I go into windowed mode the "InfotextÜ" and "Infotext" get completely messed up. Kind of the same happens with the button-24. What do I have to do so that the "layout" stays the same?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>ParadisoPiccolo</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="https://i.imgur.com/XVO5fKh.png">
    <style>
    body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
    }

    h1 {
    font-size: 3.5em;
    }
    
    h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-top: 2%;
    }
    
    p {
    margin: 20px 0;
    line-height: 1.5;
    }
    
    ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
    
    header {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    }
    
    li {
    margin: 10px 0;
    }
    
    .content {
    position: relative; 
    padding: 20px 1px;
    padding-left: 2.5%;
    }
    
    img {
    width: 90vw;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: top;
    }
    
    #slideshow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 55%;
    left: 12%;
    width: 15%;
    height: 16%;
    }
    
    #slideshow img {
    width: 170%;
    height: 170%;
    object-fit: cover;
    }

    #menu {
    position: fixed;  
    width: 100%;  
    background-color: #333;  
    color: #fff;  
    z-index: 2;  
    padding: 0;
    }

    
    .Infotext {
    position: absolute;
    top: 57%;
    left: 40%;
    font-size: 160%;

    }

    .InfotextÜ {
    position: absolute;
    top: 53.5%;
    left: 40%;
    font-family: Arno Pro Caption;
    font-size: 225%;
    }
    
    .button-24 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 90%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 9%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    background: #FF4742;
    border: 1px solid #FF4742;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 1px 2px 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: nunito,roboto,proxima-nova,"proxima nova",sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: 800;
    line-height: 16px;
    min-height: 40px;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 12px 43px;
    text-align: center;
    text-rendering: geometricprecision;
    text-transform: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .button-24:hover,
    .button-24:active {
    background-color: initial;
    background-position: 0 0;
    color: #FF4742;
    }

    .button-24:active {
    opacity: .5;
    }

    footer {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    }
    </style>

    </head>
    <body>  
    <header> 
    <div id="slideshow">
    (...)
    </div>
    <p class="InfotextÜ">Paradiso Piccolo</p>
    <p class="Infotext">Das Paradiso Piccolo ist eine Ferienwohnung am See. <br> 
    Sehr schön gelegen direkt    am Seeufer.<br> Von der eigenen Liegewiese am Strand geht's raus auf <br>
    den See zum Schwimmen, Surfen, Segeln oder Kiten. <br> Vom Balkon genießt man am Abend den Blick auf
    das Seepanorama. <br> Eine Perle am See.</p>
    <img id="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/O0jKPtk.jpg" alt="Foto">
    </header>
    (...)
    </html>
```

I tried setting the position to relative but that just puts the text above the image and I get confused even more. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In this situation (HTML) there is NO NEED at all to use absolute positioning (which is the cause for your troubles). Just erase all those position values (except for navigation and similar elements) and rebuild the whole thing.

Comment: I just tried it out but the text just moves to the top left-hand corner above the image but I want the text to be "in front" of the image at the position it is right now (in full screen).